# Unknown limit of convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence

Are there any function or infinite series which is known to converge to a value, but whose value of convergence is unknown (impossible to prove)?

Comment: Just about everything which converges cannot be (explicitly) computed analytically.

Comment: The [Halting probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant) is a classic example. There's no algorithm to calculate it to arbitrary precision and in any proof system there's a limit to the lower and upper bound you can prove for it.